# how i can prevent ionic app from reverse engineering?

Tags: cordova, ionic3, reverse-engineering, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am developing app using ionic 3 and angular 5. And I have tried to implement ProGuard in ionic app but not getting any success. I can break apk file using following link :-

[Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

So plese help me to protect my apk file from reverse engineering.

I have followed many tutorial like below
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-proguard